# Python, ошибка с '\n' , читается как строка

Tags: python, файлы, requests

```
#https://sites.google.com/view/coderprogrammers/alis_version_checher

from turtle import width
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
version ='Version - 21.0.0'
url = f"https://sites.google.com/view/coderprogrammers/alis_version_checher"
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")
version_ACTUALITY = soup.find("div", class_="jXK9ad-SmKAyb").text
if version != version_ACTUALITY:
    print('Версия устарела')
    version_ACTUA = soup.find("div", class_="jXK9ad-SmKAyb").text
    print(version_ACTUA)
    with open ('vvvv.py', 'w',  encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(version_ACTUA) 

else:
    print('Версия актуальна')
```

написал следующий код, хотел сделать автообновление файла при условии что его версия не совпадает, однако при вписании кода в файл он записывал \n строкой а не Enter, а в print() выводит тоже самое что делать, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: "кто на ком стоял?:-) Отредактируйте ответ, пожалуйста: 
 Кто "он записывал" и в каких условиях - при редактировании? Что значит "записывал \n строкой а не Enter"? (`\n` - строка, означает её перевод) Что значит "выводит тоже самое"?

Comment: @Сергей \n строкой значит что пайтон не воспринял \n как перенос на другую строку

Comment: @Сергей выводит тоже самое что и выходит в файле

Comment: @Сергей неужели не видно что в коде запускаемый скрипт записывает данные в файл vvvv.py

Comment: Да, я вообще туповат бываю, уж извините, что мне ничего не понятно из вашего описания:-) Но спасибо, что укорили, подумаю над своим поведением:-) Кстати, вообще не уверен, что будет много ответов.

Comment: Видимо вся проблема в экраннирований спец. символов

Comment: @СергейШ Восстановите свой ответ, я всё-таки не совсем то в своём ответе написал, там нужно всё-таки `div` вытягивать )

Comment: @CrazyElf но вы были первым:) мало того вы указали автору вопроса, что код не много не работает по задуманной логике, на которые я не обратил внимания :(. Я считаю, что вы должны востановить ваш ответ

Comment: Добавьте вывод `print(repr(version_ACTUA))`, пока с ваших слов не очень понятно, что там за строка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если открыть страницу по ссылке, то видно, что текст программы именно так и записан, с `\n` в виде текста, а не в виде переноса строки. Исправить это просто - заменой:

```
version_ACTUA = soup.find("div", class_="jXK9ad-SmKAyb").text.replace('\\n','\n')
```

Тогда у вас будет нормальный код скрипта, можете его записывать дальше в файл.

Остальной код там всё-равно толком не работает, там всё нужно переделывать. Но по крайней мере эту проблему можно так решить.

Например, номер версии там видимо нужно с помощью регулярного выражения вытаскивать. А сейчас вы в качестве номера версии пытаетесь брать весь код скрипта.

Comment: "помощью регулярного выражения" или поменять class в первом soup.find на более подходящий  class.

Comment: спасибо вам большое, я бы не справился

Comment: Спасибо. кстати я считаю что вопрос полезный, если подумать то затронута тема втообновления, а ваш ответ мне тоже очень помог